# How to do unit test for xaml activity with persistence in WF 4.0

Tags: unit-testing, workflow-foundation-4

I have a xaml activity with a Delay activity inside it . So when the activty reaches delay it goes to idle state and then rehydreates. How do I write a unit test showing persistence in XAML activity?

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll down on this [page](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview) you will see a heading called **Memory Store** - that's an example of how to unit test persistence. If you download the examples you will find some great code as well to assist with that.